# Can not instantiate a model's attribute based upon another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a model `M` with two fields: `a1` and `a2`.

When creating a new `M`, I am passing a value for `a1` from the view.

In the model, I want to generate a value for `a2` based upon the value of `a1`, as shown underneath:

```
class M < ActiveRecord::Base
      after_save :derive_a2

    private

      def derive_a2
        @a2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@a1).read)
      end

    end
```

On the line `@a2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@a1).read)` I get an error stating that `@a1` is null. However, this should not be the case as I am passing the attribute `a1` from the view.

The method `derive_a2` is executed using the `after_save` lifecycle method so it should access the record after it has been saved.

Why does the field `a1` appear as null?

Comment: Please show relevant controller action where M is instantiated and a1 is set.

Comment: Try `self.a1` instead of `@a1`.

Comment: Try to put `derive_a2` function from `private` part.

Comment: @PeterTretyakov how would that solve anything?

Comment: @Mischa that worked! Thanks! Do you have any idea why? I thought those two notations are equivalent.

Comment: In a plain class they are, but not in ActiveRecord subclasses. I was looking for some documentation on this, but couldn't find it so quickly. In any case, from an OO perspective it'd be better to use the method that encapsulates the instance variable instead of the instance variable itself.